# Find all char are enclosed with +

Tags: c#, regex

I have long string , now I need to find that in string each char (not digit) are enclosed with + sign.

For example

- 1q+1q+1 : result- false
- 1+q+1+q+1 : result- true
- q+a+123  : result - false

As you can see each char must with surrounded by +, to be true.

**Note** : Need to check only char between `[a-zA-Z]`. If there is no any alphabet in string then it should return true. (e.g : 1+1+1 or 1++.25,+5  will return true)

I'm trying to do with regex. but it's not working.

```
public static bool IsValidPattern(string str)
  {
     return Regex.IsMatch(str, @"\?\+[a-zA-Z]\+$");
  }
```

[**.NetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9R5aGh)

Comment: Your method will return true if any match is found, regardless of whether non-conforming characters are present. Shouldn't you be checking for something like `[^+].[^+]` and returning false if found?

Comment: What about `"1+1+1"`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere : I just need to check only char. `1+1+1` will return true. as there is no char between `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: how about "+1+1+1+" or  "1+1+1+" or  "+1+1+1"

Comment: @PaulF : it will also return true. as there is no char between `[a-zA-Z]` in your example.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "there is no char between [a-zA-Z]" - would "1+123+1" be valid as the are no alphabetic characters

Comment: Try `return !Regex.IsMatch(str, @"(?<!\+)[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z](?!\+)")`

Comment: @PaulF : I mean to say that let suppose input string is `+1112.,+1` then is is valid for me. because there is no alphabet in this.

Comment: Thanks - that's much clearer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go the other way round and check if there is a char which is not enclosed in `+` with negative look ahead and look behind:

```
public static bool IsValidPattern(string str)
  {
     return !Regex.IsMatch(str, @"((?<!\+)[a-zA-Z])|([a-zA-Z]+(?!\+))");
  }
```

[Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iw5g5Q)

Short explanation:

`|` : is an or so matching against `((?<!\+)[a-zA-Z])` or `([a-zA-Z](?!\+))`

`((?<!\+)` is a negative lookbehind which assures that the following (`[a-zA-Z]`) is not preceded by a `\+`

`((?!\+)` is a negative lookahead which assures that the preceding (`[a-zA-Z]`) is not followed by `\+`

So the first alternative is matching strings like `'a+', 'c+'` and so on and the second one the other way round (`'+a', '+c'`) which is considered invalid.

Comment: It will fail in 3rd case `q+a+123`

Comment: Ah i didn't see, that you want to check if each char is surrounded, sorry.

Comment: It worked. :) Thanks. But can you please explain it, As I'm very new to write regex. It will help me to understand it.

Comment: Just have a look on the right side of this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oxsGyl/1) , this will explain you every element of the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Regexes have the advantege of being concise but can become quite cryptic and less maintainable at the same time.

Is there any reason why you don't want your code to clearly express what it's doing and to be able to add any other conditions in the future?

```
public static bool IsValidPattern(string str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsLetter(str[i]))
        {
            if (i == 0 || i == str.Length - 1 || str[i - 1] != '+' || str[i + 1] != '+')
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Perfect :) . No there was not any specific reason to use regex. Just for simplicity I went with regex.